# LDAP2.4でレプリケーションの設定をおこないたい

Tags: openldap

下記の環境でレプリケーションの設定を行おうとしております。

インストールパッケージ
openldap-servers-2.4.39-8.el6.x86_64.rpm
openldap-clients-2.4.39-8.el6.x86_64.rpm

マスターサーバ
mailsvr-01.local
192.168.100.41

スレーブサーバ
mailsvr-02.local
192.168.100.44

スレーブサーバの設定ファイルは下記を記述しました。

ファイル名：syncrepl.ldif

```
dn: olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcSyncRepl
olcSyncRepl: rid=001
  provider=ldap://192.168.100.41:389/
  bindmethod=simple
  binddn="cn=Manager,dc=mailsvr-01,dc=local"
  credentials=password
  type=refreshAndPersist
  interval=00:00:05:00
  searchbase="dc=mailsvr-01,dc=local"
  scope=sub
  retry="60 10 300 3"
```

下記で反映

```
#ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:// -f syncrepl.ldif
```

下記で確認

```
#ldapsearch -x -LLL -H ldap:/// -b dc=mailsvr-01,dc=local
```

この場合に、マスターサーバの反映されたエントリ情報を参照したいのですが、
自分自身(スレーブサーバ)のエントリ情報が表示されてしまいます。

設定のどこに問題の可能性があるかご指摘いただけますでしょうか。

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

スレーブとマスターの情報が合っていないということですか？
確認ですが、更新はマスターのみに行なっているのですよね？ 
スレーブが空の状態にしてから同期をとっていますか？

もし、同期がとれていないのでしたら、スレーブの slapd を停止し、/var/lib/ldap/ 以下の DB_CONFIG 以外のファイルを削除(または別のディレクトリに移動)して空の状態で slapd を起動すると同期すると思います。

Comment: @Taichiさん

ありがとうございます。上記の方法で解決しました。